# PHP square brackets in object variable - how to call the variable

Tags: php

I have a simple answer I just can't solution to:

var_dump(obj) =

```
object(stdClass)#15 (3) {
  ["properties"]=>
  object(stdClass)#14 (2) {
    ["user_name"]=>
    string(4) "somename"
    ["email_address"]=>
    string(12) "test@test.com"
  ["arrays"]=>
  object(stdClass)#17 (1) {
    ["sites[]"]=>
    object(stdClass)#18 (4) {
      ["0"]=>
      int(1)
      ["1"]=>
      int(1)
      ["2"]=>
      int(0)
      ["3"]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
}
```

How to call the 'sites[]' object in my 'obj'?

I tried the following:

```
obj->sites[]
obj->{'sites[]'}
```

Both options aren't working...

Comment: @Machavity, the variable being dumped is not an array, it's an `stdClass` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be better to clean up the code that generates that object, but you should be able to access the `sites[]` object via:

```
$sites = $obj->arrays->{'sites[]'};
```

However `$sites` will still be an object, so you would need to access its elements in a similarly awkward way:

```
echo $sites->{'0'};
```

<del>It would be better to cast it to an array at that point:</del>

```
$sites = (array) $obj->arrays->{'sites[]'};
```

<del>Then you can access as an array:</del>

```
echo $sites[0];
```

EDIT, seams you cannot access array elements indexed by a numerical string.

A better option (as discovered by a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696119/access-array-element-indexed-by-numerical-string) i just posted about this) would be to use `get_object_vars`:

```
$sites = get_object_vars($obj->arrays->{'sites[]'});
```

Then you can access as an array:

```
echo $sites[0];
```

Comment: Lol, I forgot to add 'arrays' there, dumb me. I already cleaned up the naming. Thank you for your help