# Access array element indexed by numerical string

Tags: php

I have encountered something odd.

I have a php array, indexed with numerical keys.
However it appears impossible to access any of the elements because php automatically treats numerical strings as integers, causing an illegal offset notice.

Under normal circumstances its imposable to create a php array with numerical string indexes, but it can happen with type casting.

To reproduce:

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->{'1'} = 'one';

$array = (array) $object;

var_dump($array);
/* produces
array(1) {
  ["1"]=>
  string(3) "one"
}
*/

//none of the following will work
$key = '1';
echo $array[1], $array['1'], $array["1"], $array[(string)1], $array[$key];
```

Is this just an edge case bug? I only encountered the problem when attempting to improve my answer for [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695149/php-square-brackets-in-object-variable-how-to-call-the-variable)

Live code example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/dFSlH1

Comment: I think it's happening when you convert from object to array. Cause it's working fine if it's an associative array. Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/wskYI9

Comment: also, if you use the rather messy `json_decode(json_encode($object), true)` approach, this issue doesn't happen

Comment: Some info here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting

Comment: String keys containing valid integer values would be cast to integer keys automatically in “normal” array creation – but it seems casting from object to array doesn’t apply the same logic. It can be fixed however, by using `$array = array_combine(array_keys($array), array_values($array));` after your line that creates the array from the object. http://codepad.viper-7.com/v5rGJa

Comment: to add to danjam's comment... `with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are unaccessible; `

Comment: @danjam Are, well spotted. So it is documented. Though i would still consider it a bug.

Comment: @Steve not a bug, it's a language "feature" :)

Comment: @Dale yeah, im am used to finding features like this in php, but this one was new to me!

Comment: @CBroe Thats a valid answer, you might as well post it

Comment: @Dale Your 1st comment is also a valid answer

Comment: @Steve, yea but honestly I prefer the get_object_vars method over mine :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unbelievable but this is normal behavior in php, it was considered as a bug ([link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45346)) in the year 2008.

But they just pointed out to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) for the cast with `(array)`:

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose
>   elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable
>   names, with a few notable exceptions: **integer properties are**
>   **unaccessible**;

You can use [get_object_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) instead:

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->{'1'} = 'one';

$array = get_object_vars( $object );

$key = '1';
echo $array[1]."<br>";
echo $array['1']."<br>";
echo $array["1"]."<br>";
echo $array[(string)1]."<br>";
echo $array[$key]."<br>";
```

Doesn't explain why this happens, but is a solution to avoid the cast problem.

**Off topic** but I thought maybe it is interesting. Found this in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

To avoid these kind of problems, always use an integer OR a string as index, don't mix it up and don't use integers in a string.

Example of mixed array:

```
$array = array(
    1    => "a",
    "1"  => "b",//overrides 1
    1.5  => "c",//overrides "1"
    true => "d",//overrides 1.5
);

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
$vars  = get_object_vars($object);
echo $vars[1];
```

Comment: oh great, you were faster than me :)

Answer (score 2):

String keys containing valid integer values would be cast to integer keys automatically in “normal” array creation – but it seems casting from object to array doesn’t apply the same logic.

It can be fixed however, by using

```
$array = array_combine(array_keys($array), array_values($array));
```

after your line that creates the array from the object. http://codepad.viper-7.com/v5rGJa

---

Although, same as Dave already said in his comment, using `get_object_vars` looks like a “cleaner” solution to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    var_dump($key);
    var_dump($value);
}
```

shows

```
string(1) "1"
string(3) "one"
```

But `echo $array['"1"'];` gives

```
E_NOTICE :  type 8 -- Undefined index: "1" -- at line 8
```

That's strange!